# Wordpress rewrite URL to include creation date as slug

Tags: wordpress

I have a hierarchical post type called race.
For example the "NYC marathon" has various children:
"NYC marathon 2014", "NYC marathon 2013", etc...

Currently the url for each child looks like
http://example.com/races/nyc-marathon/nyc-marathon-2014

I would like to convert it into
http://example.com/races/nyc-marathon/2014
where "2014" is the year of the post creation date.

Any suggestion?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want all posts to be rewritten using that format or just this specific post type?

Comment: Just this specific post type

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this plugin to allow customized permalink structure for custom post types: [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)

Then just use the following format:

```
/%postname%/%year%/
```

Comment: Thanks. However this solution displays the year of the parent post. I would like to display the year of the childpost